# Oscillation of $f$ equal to $0$ implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Define $$o(f,a) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} M(f) - m(f)$$

where $M(f) = \sup \{f(x) : x \in Q, |x - a| < \delta  \}$ and $m(f) = \inf \{f(x) : x \in Q, |x - a| < \delta  \}$

There is a well known result that says $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $o(f,a) = 0$.

I am just wondering if this can be reformulated as

> $f$ is continuous if and only if $o(f,x) = 0$ for every $x \in Q$ where $Q$ is the domain of $f$.

Here is a sketch of the proof for the forward direction

> Since $f$ is continuous (at a point say $a$), then given $\epsilon >0$, we have $|x - a| < \delta \implies | f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon$. By definition of $M(f)$ and $m(f)$, we also have
>
> $$M(f) \leq f(x) + \epsilon,$$ and $$f(x) - \epsilon \leq m(f).$$ for every $x \in Q$.
> So we then have $M(f) - m(f) \leq 2\epsilon $

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, that is, $f$ is continuous at every point in its domain $Q$, then your claim follows from the result.